# Kiosk Mode on non Chrome OS

Tags: web-applications, chrome

My team is working on a progressive web app. We've been searching for a solution to so that viewers of our app cannot exit the app (it's an in shop app, which we use at our stores that shows content related to the store). I've found several solutions involving putting physical covers over the devices back/home buttons, as well as installing third party software that disables usage of all other apps/locks the screen to one specific app. I've also found the solution of adding "kiosked_enabled":"true" to the manifest.json file. However, upon viewing this link (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/kiosk_enabled#kiosk_enabled) I see that this seems to be a solution specific to Chrome OS/Chrome devices.

So my question is:

1. Do progressive web apps support kiosk mode on non-Chrome devices.?
2. If so, how can this be implemented?
3. If not, what is a solution that my team can implement with our code base to lock the device to only use our application that doesn't use a physical cover over the hardware or a third party app (would love to know how these third party applications do this)?

Comment: what form does this app take? is it the same one from https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/354684

Answer (score 1):

Most operating systems allow you to specify the program used as a login shell or initial process. In both Unix-based and Windows-based operating systems, Kiosk-mode is usually implemented by setting the login shell to your program, for example, in Windows, the standard login shell is `explorer.exe`, but you can replace it with, say, `firefox.exe`, if you want. I believe, there are special Kiosk forks of most major open source web browsers, and even the stock browsers sometimes have Kiosk support built in (e.g. [`iexplore.exe -k` starts Internet Explorer in Kiosk mode: "The browser opens in a maximized window that does not display the address bar, the navigation buttons, or the status bar."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh826025.aspx))